# Importing Keras models into Colaboratory from Google Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, keras, hdf5, google-colaboratory

I am trying to find method to load a Keras model saved in .h5 format which is stored in Google Drive directly into a Colaboratory worksheet for use as a Keras model (without downloading to desktop first, already have method for that).

I have succeeded in loading the .h5 file using the Colaboratory tutorials for Drive REST API:

```
# Download the '.h5' file from google drive

file_id = '1uBtlaggVyWshwcyP6kEI-y_W3P8D26sz'

import io
from io import BytesIO   
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
downloaded = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(downloaded, request)
done = False
while done is False:
  status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
  if status:
      print("Download %%%d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
  print("Download Complete!")

downloaded.seek(0)

print('Downloaded file contents are: {}'.format(downloaded.read()))
```

Which outputs:

```
Download %100%.
Download Complete!
Downloaded file contents are: b'\x89HDF\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00...(etc)
```

And it appears that downloaded.read() gives a kind of byte string.

My question is how can I then convert this byte string into a .h5 form so I can then call load_model from Keras?

Comment: (the tutorial with full method for authorizing Google Drive etc available here: https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to just write it to a file:

```
with open('/tmp/model.h5', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(downloaded.read())
```

and then create a file to pass to keras as `h5py.File('/tmp/model.h5')`.